# How to update a value inside nested arrays in a jsonb object?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I got the following `jsonb` content in PostgreSQL:

```
{
    "segments": [
        {
            "type": "year",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "length",
                    "value": "4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "month",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "length",
                    "value": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "dayOfMonth",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "length",
                    "value": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "autoIncrement",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "scope",
                    "value": "plant"
                },
                {
                    "name": "period",
                    "value": "day"
                },
                {
                    "name": "length",
                    "value": "10"
                },
                {
                    "name": "paddingCharactor",
                    "value": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want update the period from 'day' to 'forever' in *segments -> type=autoIncrement -> settings -> period*

I have tried `jsonb_set` and manually combine data after split it, both failed.

Is there any idea for updating the value?

Comment: The table name is `serial_rules` and the field name is `rule`

Comment: Not that this can't be done, but I would suggest not to store your data as JSON in the database if you're interested in regularly manipulating  its deeper contents. Use simple relational tables storing individual elements separately, which makes it easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Although possible with a highly unreadable query, the PostgreSQL `jsonb_set` function is not (yet) able to utilize a JSONPath for selecting the element to replace, but there is [work in-progress](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CACPNZCt5B8jDCCGQiFoSuqmg-za_NCy4QDioBTLaNRih9%2B-bXg%40mail.gmail.com#ad7425c57101b7005ac831d9d6a95668) related to [this topic](https://github.com/obartunov/sqljsondoc/blob/master/README.jsonpath.md).

For the time being, it probably is best to write a helper function.

As I am preferring Python, here's my take (generic enough to support different scenarios but tailored enough to not be unusable):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_change_setting(val jsonb, segment_filter jsonb, setting text, replacement jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    TRANSFORM FOR TYPE jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $$
v_new = val
tmp = v_new["segments"]
for item in tmp:
    if (segment_filter.items() <= item.items()):
        settings = item["settings"]
        for s in settings:
            if (s["name"] == setting):
                s["value"] = replacement

return v_new
$$;
```

...and can be invoked as follows for your requirement:

```sql
UPDATE serial_rules
SET rule = jsonb_change_setting(config, '{"type":"autoIncrement"}', 'period', '"forever"')
WHERE ...
```

Beware that this function requires PostgreSQL 11 and extensions plpython3u and jsonb_plpython3u (for the automatic jsonb handling).

A version for PostgreSQL 9.6+ (where the `jsonb_plpython3u` type converter extension is not available) would be:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_change_setting(val jsonb, segment_filter jsonb, setting text, replacement jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $$
import json
v_new = json.loads(val)
tmp = v_new["segments"]
for item in tmp:
    if (segment_filter.items() <= item.items()):
        settings = item["settings"]
        for s in settings:
            if (s["name"] == setting):
                s["value"] = replacement

return json.dumps(v_new)
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the given `jsonb` value as requested:

```
WITH cte(j) AS (
   SELECT jsonb '{ ... }'
   )
SELECT jsonb_set(j, '{segments,-1,settings,1,value}'::text[], '"forever"')
FROM   cte;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=87f8160c259f8cf9ab48681db06b94df)*

But I am not sure you have been asking the right *question*.
The hard part is to know the array position in each nested array. I took the last element (`-1`) of the outer array and the second (`1`) of the inner. Here's how you make that fully dynamic with pure SQL:

- [Update nth element of array using a WHERE clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193452/3684)

Consider a normalized design instead, [like Kaushik suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730449/how-to-update-value-in-the-following-jsonb-content-in-postgresql/55733770#comment98141772_55730449).

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for the answers, the final solution is directly replace json content after cast it to text and then cast back to jsonb.

The problem is how to detect which element is the right one to be updated in the array and a single struct has two layers of array. So I think the best way to replace its content is using replace function.

Comment: Imagine a production environment, lots of records, lots of text inside the JSONB field. Good luck cleaning up that mess with this approach.